# "Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string"

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

**When running my test, the following error appears:**
`"after each" hook for "creates a new artist in the database"
Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

**Error points to the following:**

```
// helper.js
const db = require("../src/db");

afterEach(async () => {
  await db.query("TRUNCATE Artists CASCADE");
});
```

**'db' file is as follows:**

```
`// db/index.js
const { Pool } = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool();

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
};`
```

**Here is how the test file looks:**

```
// artist-create.test.js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../src/app");
const db = require("../src/db");

describe("create artist", () => {
  describe("/artists", () => {
    describe("POST", () => {
      it("creates a new artist in the database", async () => {
        const { status, body } = await request(app).post("/artists").send({
          name: "Tame Impala",
          genre: "Rock",
        });

        expect(status).to.equal(201);
        expect(body.name).to.equal("Tame Impala");
        expect(body.genre).to.equal("Rock");

        const {
          rows: [artistData],
        } = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM Artists WHERE id = ${body.id}`);
        expect(artistData.name).to.equal("Tame Impala");
        expect(artistData.genre).to.equal("Rock");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**the .env & .env.test files look like this:**

```
// .env
PGUSER=postgres
PGHOST=localhost
PGPASSWORD=password
PGDATABASE=music_library_dev
PGPORT=5432
PORT=3000

// .env.test
PGUSER=postgres
PGHOST=localhost
PGPASSWORD=password
PGDATABASE=music_library_api_test
PGPORT=5432
PORT=3000
```

This is my first time using stackoverflow for help, so please let me know if any further details are required! I'd be happy to provide more information if need be, I don't want to completely fill the page by pasting all the code I've written if it's not necessary.

I've tried to change the password in order to bypass the issue, yet this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you're using SASL and not, e.g. md5 for the authentication method? Check the docs on your library

Comment: In your db/index.js file, you are not passing any connection details to the Pool. Do you have a default PostgreSQL configuration on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, update the db/index.js file as follows:

```
// db/index.js
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const envFile = environment === "test" ? ".env.test" : ".env";
dotenv.config({ path: envFile });

const pool = new Pool();

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
};
```

This modification fixes the password issue by loading the appropriate environment variables from.env.test while running tests. Make sure the dotenv library has been installed using npm install dotenv.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, the issue has now fixed thanks to your suggestion! Much appreciated :)